# python3: Miller-Rabin Test, where to put the loop?

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I have this implementation of the miller-Rabin test:

```
def miller_rabin(N):
    if N % 2 == 0:
        return False
    n = N // 2
    t = 1
    while n % 2 == 0:
        n = n // 2
        t += 1
    a = random.randrange(1, N-1)
    u = gmpy2.powmod(a, n, N)
    if u == 1 or N-u == 1:
        return True
    for k in range(1, t):
        u = gmpy2.powmod(u, 2, N)
        if N-u == 1:
            return True
    return False
```

Since it is a probabilistic test, I want to repeat it k times.
If I define this here

```
def miller_rabin_prob(N, rounds):
    for i in range(rounds):
        if miller_rabin(N) == False:
            return False
    return True
```

it works.
But I want to implement the number of rounds in one code.
But If I do

```
def miller_rabin(N, rounds):
    if N % 2 == 0:
        return False
    n = N // 2
    t = 1
    while n % 2 == 0:
        n = n // 2
        t += 1
    for i in range(rounds):
        a = random.randrange(1, N-1)
        u = gmpy2.powmod(a, n, N)
        if u == 1 or N-u == 1:
            return True
        for k in range(1, t):
            u = gmpy2.powmod(u, 2, N)
            if N-u == 1:
                return True
    return False
```

the results are even worse.

Comment: *"...the results are even worse."* What do you mean? Are the results incorrect? Maybe you can [edit] your question and put there sample (small) input and expected output.